# join zend applications on request

Tags: php, zend-framework, module, content-management-system, zend-application

How could I `join` 2 or more zend applications inside another one?
In other words, let's assume that I have this structure:

```
    /core
        /application
        /public
        ...
    /app1
        /application
        /public
        ...
    /app2
        /application
        /public
        ...
```

When a access http://some_url.com/core, I want o show the `core` application but, when I access http://some_url.com/app1, I want to show the `core` + `app1` application.
Basically, it should show the same thing of http://some_url.com/core but with extra links/actions that exists on `app1` application.

The same thing should occur with http://some_url.com/app2 (core + app2).

I thought I could create a different `index.php` for applications app1 and app2 in order to load the "core" application but, my problem is that I don't know how could I access a controller/action of app1 or app2 if I do that, using for example, 
 http://some_url.com/app1/controller_A/action_B

I'm using Zend Framework 1.11.

**EDIT**

I saw somewhere a function named `addControllerPath`. Can anyone tell me if it would work for what I want?

Comment: Are you using ZF1 or ZF2?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I'm using ZF 1.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the server uri, and choose your application in index.php

```
// Define path to application directory
$uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
if (strpos($uri, 'core') == 1) {
    defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
        || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../core'));
}
elseif (strpos($uri, 'app1') == 1) {
    defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
        || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../app1'));
}
elseif (strpos($uri, 'app2') == 1) {
    defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
        || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../app2'));
}
else {
    defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
        || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../default'));
}
```

instead the Zend default

```
// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));
```

Comment: Right, but after I choose the correct `APPLICATION_PATH`, how could I access to a controller of other application if it is not in the `APPLICATION_PATH` previously specified?

Comment: This solution will work for different applications (no interactions between them).
Why don't you use modules? (module core, app1, app2 ...)

Comment: Unfortunately, i can't use modules =S. Isn't there any solution that could make me access a controller inside of `app1` if it doesn't exist on `core`? Can't I overwrite the Zend Autoloader to do that?

Comment: They are independent applications. I don't know how to access external  application (and its controller).

Comment: Could `addControllerPath` help me with the access to other application controllers?

Comment: Ok, I managed to use modules instead of applications but, I can assure that addControllerPath + Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader can help too if someone need to load something of other application. In my case, I didn't continued with that because I managed to get a way using modules as Rafael suggested.